# Setting CoS (PCP, 802.1P) in Ethernet frame

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Is there any way I can manipulate the value of Priority Code Point [(PCP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1p) field in the Ethernet frame from my application (e.g. using `setsockopt()`)? I would like to avoid low level hacks with creating Ethernet frame from scratch.

I've searched in manual pages `socket(7)` and `ip(7)` but there is no option for controlling Ethernet frames fields.

If this is relevant I need it for TCP socket.

Comment: Can't you use e.g. the IP TOS flags? (`IP_TOS` for `setsockopt`)

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: No, I need to set PCP.

Comment: If I set the IP_TOS with certain value, does Ethernet also sets a corresponding PCP value internally or Ethernet does not care about IP_TOS field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the vlan priority field by using sockopt():

```
int priority = 7;
setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PRIORITY, &priority, sizeof(priority));
```

In the file net/8021q/vlan_dev.c you can see, that the skb->priority field is used for the VLAN 802.1Q TCI...

Comment: You are probably right. I've found this: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/8021q/vlan.h#L12 and this: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/sock.c#L709 and this: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/raw.c#L357 which seem to confirm your answer

Answer (score 1):

There are ingress and egress mappings on each VLAN device. For example:

```
vconfig add eth0 333
vconfig set_egress_map eth0.333 2 4
vconfig set_egress_map eth0.333 3 5
cat /proc/net/vlan/eth0.333
```

You can see mappings on the last two lines.